# Как вставить линию между грид блоками

Tags: css, css-grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сверстал данную секцию при помощи грид сетки, но появилась проблема не могу сделать линию посередине, использовал ::after но добавляет под нижний текст, border-right не вариант, потому что линия градиент.

Comment: Добавить место в гриде специально под линию шириной в 1-2 пикселя?)

Comment: Выложите код на Codepen, чтобы на Вашем примере показать решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуть-чуть ты с :after недоработал. Держи:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 21px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.block.with_separator:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -12px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9b1f21 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="block with_separator">Block 1</div>
  <div class="block with_separator">Block 2</div>
  <div class="block">Block 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: я понимаю значения right 12, но это немного странно выгляди, как я считаю все же проще создать третий блок с шириний 1px

Comment: можно, конечно. но представьте себе, что у вас не полный контроль над HTML страницы, например, используется какой-нибудь фреймворк, CMS, или платформа повышенной  дебильности (наподобие  SalesForce+Lightning), или просто надо обстилить, не  трогая структуру...